# why to use Promise.catch() instead of Promise.then()

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a rejected promise somewhere in my promise chain like this. I know following code will work similarly.

```
let promise = Promise.resolve(3);
let p1 = promise.then(() => 2)
                .then(() => {throw 'some error'})
                .then(null, (err) => {console.log(err)})


let p2 = promise.then(() => 2)
                .then(() => {throw 'some error'})
                .catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
```

Is there any difference conceptually in chaining promises with `.then(null, (error) {})` instead of just `.catch((err) => {})`

Comment: Why would they be equal, whether you `.then` or `.catch`? You're creating two separate promise chains; even if the resulting resolved *value* is the same they're different objects.

Comment: For similar reasons, `{} !== {}`. They're completely separate objects

Comment: @CertainPerformance  thanks didn't knew this until now. :(

Comment: As an aside, if you're looking to compare objects, you can use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to do so. `JSON.stringify({}) === JSON.stringify({})`. That way you're comparing strings instead of different objects.

Comment: They are the same. It's documented pretty well here: [MDN Catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Promise.catch()` is equal to `Promise.then(null, callback)`. You can use these interchangably. However Promise.catch is more descriptive and has the following advantages:

1. Easier to know that it is a error handling mechanism when you read .catch than when you read `.then(null, callback)`
2. Actually less code because you can leave out the `null` as a first argument of `.then()`

To conclude, there is no functional difference. However, `.catch()` is more descriptive and less code and thus superior.

As for the promise chaining it doesn't have any effect as they are functionally similar.

Comment: Just a note, that `then(f1, failf)` is not the same.  If an error happens in `f1`, `failf` will NOT get triggered.

Comment: I wish they made `.then()` take just one argument. It leads to confusion when you read 3rd party code.